# Filling gap between pipe and wall- creating a fire stop

Tags: fire-hazard

I got my condo inspected and the inspector said I had a fire hazard as there’s a gap between the pipe of my kitchen sink and the wall (an open space). I need to fill that hole then use a fire barrier sealant. How do I fill that hole/gap? What do I need to use?

Thanks!

Comment: Pictures or dimensions of the hole in question, also where on earth are you located?

Comment: Is this pipe a water pipe, or a drain pipe? What material is it made from, for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Home improvement stores generally carry the correct caulking for a fire stop. It is Fire-Barrier caulk or Fire-Stop, it is usually color coded so the inspector will know you used the correct one.

Check building codes in your area to know which one to use most are rated for 4 hours. Be careful if you order it off the internet because if the color is wrong you fail, even if it meets the local code.

For the gap there is also expanded foam that you can use, just make sure its rated and meets local codes.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the wall being penetrated and the type of pipe, this may not be correct; some pipes and tubes need to be protected with an intumescent pinch-off seal...

Comment: Additionally, I wouldn't necessarily count on the products at your local store meeting local code. I have about 7 big-box stores within equal driving time of my house, but they're all in different cities, and each city may have its own slight variations in code and inspectors. I'd imagine they all buy their supplies based on a corporate order list with allowances for local purchasing habits more than local building codes.